# CUploadedFile create manyally

Tags: php, yii

I want to offer 2 ways of uploading files - with `<input type='file'>` and remote upload by URL.

Is it possible to create a CUploadedFile using data from a remote url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remote upload is actually not an upload, rather the user submits the link and you need to copy it over to your server. 
Consider CUploadedFile to be used only for the upload part and handover to the next file handler.
Once done with upload or copy, You might want to use another file management utility like cfile extension here http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/cfile/ to manage both your files already "copied/uploaded" to your desired directory.